# The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided, even signature created

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

Signature is created successfully when passed as authorization to access service, facing an error like
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.

Below the class used to create the authorization. Kindly assist.

> public class Canonical {
>
> ```
>   //public static String authorization_header;
>   public static String auth() throws Exception  {
>       
>       //canonical string creation
>       String currentDate  = getDate();
>       String xAmzDate = getTimeStamp();
>       String region = "eu-west-1";
>       String serviceName ="execute-api";
>       
>       String canonical_uri = "pathdetailsofservice";
>       
>       URL url = new URL("endpointurl");
>       String req_query_string = orderQuery(url );
>       String canonical_querystring = req_query_string;
>       String host ="dataservices.whssng.uk";
>       String method ="POST";
>       String ContentType ="application/json";
>       String canonical_headers = "host:" + host + "\n" + "x-amz-date:" + xAmzDate + "\n";
>       String signed_headers = "Content-Type;host;x-amz-date";
>       String secret_key ="secretkey";
>       String access_key ="accesskey";
>       
>       String request_parameters = "";
>       String payload_hash = generateHex(request_parameters);
>       String canonical_request = method + "\n" + canonical_uri + "\n" + ContentType+ "\n" + canonical_querystring + "\n" + canonical_headers + "\n" + signed_headers + "\n" + payload_hash;
>       System.out.println("canonical_request"+"\n"+canonical_request);
>       
>       //Create  String to Sign
>       
>       String algorithm = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256";
>               String credential_scope = currentDate + "/" + region + "/" + serviceName + "/" + "aws4_request";
>               String hash_canonical_request = generateHex(canonical_request);
>               String string_to_sign = algorithm + "\n" +  xAmzDate + "\n" +  credential_scope + "\n" +  hash_canonical_request;
>       System.out.println("string_to_sign"+"\n"+string_to_sign);
>       
>   ////Calculate the String to Sign
>       
>   byte[] signing_key = getSignatureKey(secret_key, xAmzDate, region, serviceName);
>   byte[] signature =hmac_sha256(signing_key, string_to_sign);
>   String strHexSignature = bytesToHex(signature);
>    System.out.println("Signature:"+strHexSignature);
>    
>    
>   //Add Signing information to Variable
>    
>   
>   String authorization_header = algorithm + " " + "Credential=" + access_key + "/" + credential_scope + ", " +  "SignedHeaders=" +
> ```
>
> signed_headers + ", " + "Signature=" + strHexSignature;
> System.out.println("Authorization:"+authorization_header);
> return authorization_header;
>
> ```
> }
>
>   
> private static String generateHex(String data) {
>         MessageDigest messageDigest;
>         try {
>             messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
>             messageDigest.update(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
>             byte[] digest = messageDigest.digest();
>             return String.format("%064x", new java.math.BigInteger(1, digest));
>         } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
>         return null;
>     }
>
> public static String getDate() {
>     DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
>     dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));//server timezone
>     return dateFormat.format(new Date());
> }
>
>
> public static String orderQuery(URL url) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
>
>     String orderQueryString = "";
>     Map<String, String> queryPairs = new LinkedHashMap<>();
>     String queryParams = url.getQuery();
>
>     if (queryParams != null) {
>         String[] pairs = queryParams.split("&");
>     
>         for (String pair : pairs) {
>             int idx = pair.indexOf("=");
>             queryPairs.put(URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(0, idx), "UTF-8"), URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(idx + 1), "UTF-8"));
>         }
>        TreeMap<String, String> orderQueryArray = new TreeMap<String, String>(queryPairs);
>         orderQueryString  = urlEncodeUTF8(orderQueryArray);
>     }
>     return orderQueryString;
> }
>
>
> public static String urlEncodeUTF8(String s) {
>     try {
>         return URLEncoder.encode(s, "UTF-8");
>     } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
>         throw new UnsupportedOperationException(e);
>     }
> }
>
> public static String urlEncodeUTF8(Map<?,?> map) {
>     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
>     for (Map.Entry<?,?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
>         if (sb.length() > 0) {
>             sb.append("&");
>         }
>         sb.append(String.format("%s=%s",
>             urlEncodeUTF8(entry.getKey().toString()),
>             urlEncodeUTF8(entry.getValue().toString())
>         ));
>     }
>     return sb.toString();       
> }
>
>
>
> public static String getTimeStamp() {
>     DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'");
>     dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));//server timezone
>     return dateFormat.format(new Date());
> }
>
>
> public static byte[] getSignatureKey(String key, String dateStamp, String regionName, String serviceName) throws Exception {
>     byte[] kSecret = ("AWS4" + key).getBytes("UTF-8");
>     byte[] kDate = hmac_sha256(kSecret, dateStamp);
>     byte[] kRegion = hmac_sha256(kDate, regionName);
>     byte[] kService = hmac_sha256(kRegion, serviceName);
>     byte[] kSigning = hmac_sha256(kService, "aws4_request");
>     return kSigning;
> }
>
>
>
>
> public static byte[]  hmac_sha256(byte[] key, String data) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
>     Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
>     SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "HmacSHA256");
>     mac.init(secretKeySpec);
>     byte[] digest = mac.doFinal(data.getBytes());
>     return digest;
>      
>  
>     
> }
> final protected static char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
> private static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
>     char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
>     for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
>         int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
>         hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
>         hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
>     }
>     return new String(hexChars).toLowerCase();
> }
> }
> ```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use AWS SDK for Java, rather then do it all from scratch?

Comment: how i can rectify the above issue@Marcin